# Confidence Interval for Normal$(\theta,\theta^2)$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, confidence-interval

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ a simple random sample $$X_i\sim N(\theta,\theta^2)$$

I want to find a confidence interval for the mean using a pivotal quantity. I read this answer
[Confidence Intervals - distribution of a Pivot?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241855/confidence-intervals-distribution-of-a-pivot/2241914#2241914) and the pivotal quantity should be
$$\frac{\bar{x}-\theta}{S/\sqrt{n}}$$

But I'm wondering if for this case I can use
$$Y=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\sim N(n\theta, n\theta^2)$$
Then my pivotal quantity will be$$\frac{Y-n\theta}{\theta\sqrt{n}}\sim N(0,1) $$

So
$$P\left(-z_{\alpha/2}<\frac{y-n\theta}{\theta\sqrt{n}}<z_{\alpha/2}\right)=1-\alpha $$
$$P\left(\frac{Y}{n+\sqrt{n}z_{\alpha/2}}<\theta<\frac{Y}{n-\sqrt{n}z_{\alpha/2}}\right)=1-\alpha $$
Is this correct too?

Comment: makes sense to me

Comment: This is fine as long as $\theta>0$.

Comment: You should have $\frac{Y-n\theta}{|\theta|\sqrt{n}}\sim N(0,1)$ to deal with the possibility of negative $\theta$

Comment: @Henry Could you explain why solving for $\theta$ as above works? It would seem to me that something goes wrong in the process, as making $\alpha$ smaller (i.e. increasing confidence) increases $z_{\alpha / 2}$, and thereby shrinks the size of the confidence interval for $\theta$—surely that can't be right?

Comment: You have some other issues to deal with first.  In particular $z_{\alpha/2}<0$ so your $P\left(-z_{\alpha/2}<\frac{y-n\theta}{\theta\sqrt{n}}<z_{\alpha/2}\right)=1-\alpha$ should be $P\left(z_{\alpha/2}<\frac{y-n\theta}{\theta\sqrt{n}}<-z_{\alpha/2}\right)=1-\alpha$ or $P\left(-z_{1-\alpha/2}<\frac{y-n\theta}{\theta\sqrt{n}}<z_{1-\alpha/2}\right)=1-\alpha$ or $P\left(z_{\alpha/2}<\frac{y-n\theta}{\theta\sqrt{n}}<z_{1-\alpha/2}\right)=1-\alpha$

Answer (score 3):

your procedure is correct. But in a very simple and standard way, simply observe that

$$\frac{X}{\theta }\sim N(1;1)$$

thus

$$\frac{\overline{X}_n}{\theta}\sim N\left( 1;\frac{1}{n} \right)$$

which is a natural Pivotal quantity....the result is the same as yours (assuming $\theta>0$)

Comment: +1. When $\theta < 0$ you also get $\frac{\overline{X}_n}{\theta}\sim N\left( 1;\frac{1}{n} \right)$.  Meanwhile $\theta = 0$ remains an issue, though if so then with probability $1$ all your observations would be exactly $0$ which might be a clue